# Variadic template constructor mixing lvalues and rvalues in a tuple

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates, perfect-forwarding

I want to defer the instantiation of a (large) bunch of classes, among which only a small subset will be instantiated. To do that, I try to capture the arguments to constructors in a variadic class which stores them in a tuple.

My problem is that I only succeeded in storing either references or copies. However, I need to forward both kinds to the constructors, at once, or I get scope problems.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

// Interface of the classes which instanciation is being deferred.
struct OpItf {
    virtual void operator()() = 0;
    virtual ~OpItf() {}
};

struct Operator : public OpItf {
    int& _i;
    int _j;
    // Need both a lvalue reference and a rvalue.
    Operator(int& i, int j) : _i(i), _j(j) {}
    void operator()() {std::cout << _i << " " << _j << std::endl;}
    virtual ~OpItf() {}
};

// The interface of the class managing the actual instanciation.
template<class Itf>
struct ForgeItf {
        virtual Itf& instanciate() = 0;
        virtual ~ForgeItf() {}
};

template<class Itf, class Op, typename... Args>
struct Forge : public ForgeItf<Itf> {

    std::tuple<Args&&...> _args;
    Itf* _instanciated;

    Forge(Args&&... args) :
        _args(std::forward<Args>(args)...),
        _instanciated(nullptr)
    { }

    Itf& instanciate()
    {
        if(_instanciated) {
            delete _instanciated;
        }
        _instanciated = op_constructor(_args);
        return *_instanciated;
    }

    virtual ~Forge() { delete _instanciated; }

    template<class T>
    Op* op_constructor(T& args) { return new Op(std::make_from_tuple<Op>(args)); }
};

// A container of forges.
template<class Itf>
struct Foundry : std::vector< ForgeItf<Itf>* > {

        template<class Op, typename... Args>
        void add(Args&&... args)
        {
            auto pfo = new Forge<Itf,Op,Args&&...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            this->push_back(pfo);
        }

        virtual ~Foundry() { for(auto p : *this) { delete p; } }
};

int main() {

    Foundry<OpItf> foundry;

    int iref = 1;

    // Store the constructors parameters.
    for(int j=0; j<3; ++j) {
        foundry.add< Operator >(iref,j);
    }

    // Change the referenced parameter before instanciations.
    iref = 2;

    // Actually instanciate.
    for(auto& forge : foundry ) {
        auto& op = forge->instanciate();
        op();
    }
}
```

Using rvalues `Args...`, the constructors get the values, but the reference to `i` is (uncorrectly) unchanged:

```
1 0
1 1
1 2
```

Using forwarding references `Args&&...`, the constructors get the reference correctly, but out-of-scope copies of `j`:

```
2 1228009304
2 1228009304
2 1228009304
```

Comment: I can't [replicate](https://godbolt.org/z/aeB9tz) this issue. You have a bunch of warnings though, so you should fix that first.

Comment: `Forge(Args&&... args) : _args(std::forward<Args>(args)...),` — Are you aware that `args` here _are not forwarding references_ here, therefore "forwarding" them might not work as you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to keep temporary values *alive* is to store them into tuple by copy. Otherwise, by storing references you will have them as *dangling*.

You can use `reference_wrapper` to store `i` as-if by reference.

Changes:

```
  foundry.add< Operator >(std::ref(iref),j);  // wrap i into reference_wrapper 
  ---
  auto pfo = new Forge<Itf,Op,std::decay_t<Args>...>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

use `std::decay_t<Args>...` to store all pack parameters by value (operation of copying `reference_wrapper` is cheap).

```
template<class Itf, class Op, typename... Args>
struct Forge : public ForgeItf<Itf> {

    std::tuple<Args...> _args;
    Itf* _instanciated;

    template<class ... Args2>
    Forge(Args2&&... args2) :
        _args(std::forward<Args2>(args2)...),
        _instanciated(nullptr)
    { }
```

because `Args` are decayed, just store: `tuple<Args...>` and make constructor taking forwarding reference to avoid redundant copies when calling constructor.

As output:

```
2 1
2 2 
2 3
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/j73tJ6)

Comment: Thanks, the use of `ref` by the user is a constraint, but one can live with it.